# ModelForm is not JSON serializable when I render in view function

Tags: django, json, forms

I have a modelform that I want to render within an existing template with a HttpResponse, I'm want to do with json (or html, in that case I don't know how to convert) but always the console retrieves in "onerror" ajax function the follow:

```
<ventas.forms.EmpleadoModelForm object at 0x103649c50> is not JSON serializable
```

That's the view function, if is not a POST request, return the render form in json format but is not working...

```
def edit_empleado(request, empleado_id):
empleado = get_object_or_404(Empleado, pk=empleado_id)    
if request.POST:
    form = EmpleadoModelForm(request.POST, instance=empleado)
    if form.is_valid():
        empleado = form.save()
        empleado.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/ventas/empleados")
    else:
        form_errors = form.errors
        return render_to_response("ventas/form_empleado.html", {'form_errors':form_errors,'form_empleado':form},
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))      
else:
    form = EmpleadoModelForm(instance=empleado)       
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            "form_empleado": form
        }), content_type="application/html")        
return render_to_response("ventas/form_empleado.html", {'form_empleado':form},
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any ideas of how to format in json?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to dump a Form instance as JSON for an application/html response. What do you want the response body to contain: the form data or the rendered form HTML ? I guess my question is: what do you want to do with the response ?

Comment: I have a modal form bootstrap that display data for edit for each row of a datatable, so, when I click edit for a row calls that view making an instance form according to his id, that form I want to serialize it with the data for print inside the modal bootstrap form that is inside of the template, my question is... is possible to do that?

Comment: @Enot You can pickle the form object, but not dump it as json. 
If you want to show form data only after some user action, then better render it beforehand, put it in a hidden div and display it whenever needed. Did I get your question right?

Comment: If I where you i'd do this is pure js.